How to use a MIDI pedal to transpose a software instrument in Logic Pro X while playing live?
I have a Logic Pro X session with some tracks that have software instruments that play when I play a physical MIDI instrument. The problem is this instrument has a quite limited note range and I need to play some notes outside its boundaries. I can get around this limitation by changing the octave manually and then resuming playing, which works for when I want to record music, but I need to do the same when playing live.
So in that context, how could I use my MIDI pedal (which I can program to emit any MIDI signal when stomping on one of its 3 buttons) to change the octave of software instruments in Logic Pro X? Is there a way to automate Logic Pro so it listens to MIDI signals and when some specific MIDI note or event is triggered, then Logic Pro transposes the software instruments one octave up or down?
